# Android Streaming Video using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, flash, video, streaming

I'm back with another problem!

I'm trying to create an app that would list a selected Livestreams, from Own3d.TV, Justin.Tv etc...

If my research isn't totally failed, I can use the MediaPlayer object to Stream video, the only question is how do I use it?

So far my code looks like this, but it's giving me an Exception when trying to prepare the MediaPlayer.

```
public class Media extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SurfaceView sw = new SurfaceView(this);
    SurfaceHolder sh = sw.getHolder();

    setContentView(sw);

    Uri ur = Uri.parse("http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=hashe");

    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    mp.setDisplay(sh);

    try {
        mp.setDataSource("http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=hashe");
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mp.start();
    //mp.setDisplay(sw);



}
}
```

Is it even possible to Stream the video from these sites using the MediaPlayer?

If not, how shoud I approach this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Will you provide a stack trace for us? If you're not sure how to get one, take a look at LogCat for eclipse (assuming that's what you're using to develop).

Comment: Hey Patrick. Are you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

when implementing mediaPlayer, try something like this, it worked fine for me: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/11/play-3gp-video-file-using-mediaplayer.html 
but I think, u cant use source like u have written in your code. You have to use some URL from where is video streamed directly with progresive streaming, not URL of html site with player embeded. You can recognize: when u write useful URL with streamed video in your internet browser, browser starts to download this streamed video in your computer. And I think, MediaPlayer supports in core .3gp or .mp4 format only..
I hope u understand my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Use `ExoPlayer` instead of `MediaPlayer`. See Android official documentation:

> ExoPlayer supports features like Dynamic adaptive streaming over HTTP (DASH), SmoothStreaming and Common Encryption, which are not supported by MediaPlayer. It's designed to be easy to customize and extend.

[ExoPlayer - Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer)